# Mask is blank in Object Recognition Kitchen (ORK)

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ORK all setup and appears to be working pretty well. I have identified a plane and saved a mesh of it. However, when trying to capture an object for detection, the pose fram shows up but the mask frame appears all black. From what I've read, it should display only the new object in the frame, correct? Has anybody else had this problem?

If anybody knows of other forums or documentation related to ORK I would appreciate it - the community seems somewhat small right now and I'm not to sure where to go with questions.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106141/mask-is-blank-in-object-recognition-kitchen-(ork)/) by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chase](https://answers.ros.org/users/9066/chase/) on 2013-12-01**:
For anyone else interested in ORK, take a look at the newly created ORK google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/object-recognition-kitchen

It was just started, but it would be cool if the ORK community also started to post here so we can all help each other with ORK specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Chase,
I believe you are trying to use the  "textured plane" mode, right?
rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane

### Well I didn't use it that way. I just printed out the capture_board and ommited the -i  option in
rosrun object_recognition_capture capture -i my_textured_plane --seg_z_min 0.01 -o silk.bag --preview

rosrun object_recognition_capture capture --seg_z_min 0.01 -o silk.bag --preview

that work well for me-> the frame is black EXCEPT the object...
As I mentioned on ROS Answers I installed ORK from source code.

Regards,
o3p7s5

---

Originally posted by [o3p7s5](https://answers.ros.org/users/9096/o3p7s5/) with karma: 86 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1